# Bootstrap Responsive Inline Form

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap inline-form that is 6 inputs then a button. It looks fine if it all fits on the screen, but as you make the screen smaller, the inputs fold underneath one at a time. I have tried wrapping each input in a col-md-2, but that makes the form look weird. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong.
Is there some way I can group the inputs together so that they collapse something like 6x1, 3x2, 2x3, 1x6?

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input name="input1" placeholder="input1" class="form-control" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input name="input2" type="number" placeholder="input2" class="form-control" step="any" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="input3">Input 3
        <input name="input3" type="checkbox" id="input3">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input name="input4" type="number" placeholder="input4" class="form-control" step="any" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" *ngIf="!property.input3">
      <input name="input5" type="number" placeholder="input5" class="form-control" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input name="input6" type="number" placeholder="input6" class="form-control" step="any">
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-default">Add</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

If running the code, you will have to resize the window.
I have also set up a [fiddle for the inline-form](https://jsfiddle.net/bebhutpq/)

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bootstraps grid system is great but it isn't perfect for everything under the sun.  If things aren't looking exactly the way you want them to you can always write overwriting css.  That being said, using their grid system I was able to come up with an example that fulfills your request above.  Let me know if this is more what you were thinking:

```
<div class="container">
  <form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2">
      <input name="input1" placeholder="input1" class="form-control" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2">
      <input name="input2" type="number" placeholder="input2" class="form-control" step="any" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-1 input3">
      <label for="input3">Input 3
      </label>
      <input name="input3" type="checkbox" id="input3">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2">
      <input name="input4" type="number" placeholder="input4" class="form-control" step="any" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2" *ngIf="!property.input3">
      <input name="input5" type="number" placeholder="input5" class="form-control" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2">
      <input name="input6" type="number" placeholder="input6" class="form-control" step="any">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-1">
      <button class="btn btn-default">Add</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

And here is a codepen link to the code: http://codepen.io/egerrard/pen/KaNxvW

Comment: That's pretty much what I want. Although when it becomes 2 columns, the div the button is in seems to overlay the rest of the form.

Comment: @Votemike updated.  I was using `col-md-12` on that div so on `sm` and `xs` it was losing its `float: left;` the codepen and answer have been updated with `col-xs-12`

Comment: @Votemike if this answer solves your issues please mark it as correct.  Otherwise let me know how I can help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap those inputs with div and `display:inline-block` style to make them stay together.